# how to enable vercel web analytics in react app

Tags: reactjs, hosting, vercel

I am trying to add analytics in my project but i don't know in which file i have to add the code,

like everyone is saying : to add this line of code in your app but the problem is which is root file in react and how to enable vercel analytics

```
import { Analytics } from '@vercel/analytics/react';

<Analytics />
```

**_**___

but i don't know in where to add please help me because i am new here.

i want to enable vercel web analytics in my react web app.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work on your project.

**main.jsx**

```
import { Analytics } from '@vercel/analytics/react';

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <>
    <Analytics />
    <App />
  </>
);
```

But if doesn't work then may be you have routes in your project then you have to put analytics in every routes or put the analytics tag in the common component which render each and every time in every route.

**App.jsx**

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: (
      <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
        <Home />
      </Suspense>
    ),
  },
  {
    path: "/movies",
    element: (
      <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
        <Movies />
      </Suspense>
    ),
  },
  {
    path: "/series",
    element: (
      <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
        <Series />
      </Suspense>
    ),
  },
  {
    path: "/anime",
    element: (
      <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
        <Anime />
      </Suspense>
    ),
  },
  {
    path: "/kids",
    element: (
      <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
        <Kids />
      </Suspense>
    ),
  },
  {
    path: "/collection",
    element: (
      <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
        <Collection />
      </Suspense>
    ),
  },
  {
    path: "/search/:type/:query",
    element: (
      <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
        <Search />
      </Suspense>
    ),
  },
  {
    path: "/:type/:id",
    element: (
      <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
        <Detail />
      </Suspense>
    ),
  },
  {
    path: "/stream/:type/:id/season?/:season?/episode?/:episode?",
    element: (
      <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
        <Stream />
      </Suspense>
    ),
  },
]);

const App = () => {
  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
};

export default App;
```

In this example I have some routes and each route have a page rendered.
And each page I have a dashboard component.

**Stream.jsx**

```
export const Stream = () => {
  return (
    <DashboardLayout>
      ...
    </DashboardLayout>
  );
};
```

So what I can do is I can put the Analytics tag inside the `DashboardLayout` Component.

**DashboardLayout.jsx**

```
import { Analytics } from '@vercel/analytics/react';

const DashboardLayout = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <div className="min-h-screen w-full">
      <SideBarContainer />
      <Analytics />
      <div className="h-full transition-all duration-300">
        {children}
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

It is important to keep in mind that you should render the analytics component on your DOM; this means it's not true that you can only put analytics on the root file. So long as it renders on the DOM, you can put it anywhere and it will function properly.